# C The local array returns null

Tags: c

Excuse me.
I am writing a base64 decoder,but I don't know why its return value is null.
But if I try to read the value of the array(Such as `printf(shellcode[i]);`),it can print the value of the array.I am a noob.

This is source code.

base64.h

```
#ifndef BASE46_H
#define BASE46_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>


/***********************************************
Encodes ASCCI string into base64 format string
@param plain ASCII string to be encoded
@return encoded base64 format string
***********************************************/
char* base64_encode(char* plain);


/***********************************************
decodes base64 format string into ASCCI string
@param plain encoded base64 format string
@return ASCII string to be encoded
***********************************************/
char* base64_decode(char* cipher);


#endif //BASE46_H
```

base64.c

```
#include "base64.h"

//编码表
char base64_table[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                     'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                     'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                     'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'};


char* base64_encode(char* plain) {

    char counts = 0;
    char buffer[3];
    char* cipher = malloc(strlen(plain) * 4 / 3 + 4);
    int i = 0, c = 0;

    for(i = 0; plain[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        buffer[counts++] = plain[i];
        if(counts == 3) {
            cipher[c++] = base64_table[buffer[0] >> 2];
            cipher[c++] = base64_table[((buffer[0] & 0x03) << 4) + (buffer[1] >> 4)];
            cipher[c++] = base64_table[((buffer[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + (buffer[2] >> 6)];
            cipher[c++] = base64_table[buffer[2] & 0x3f];
            counts = 0;
        }
    }

    if(counts > 0) {
        cipher[c++] = base64_table[buffer[0] >> 2];
        if(counts == 1) {
            cipher[c++] = base64_table[(buffer[0] & 0x03) << 4];
            cipher[c++] = '=';
        } else {                      // if counts == 2
            cipher[c++] = base64_table[((buffer[0] & 0x03) << 4) + (buffer[1] >> 4)];
            cipher[c++] = base64_table[(buffer[1] & 0x0f) << 2];
        }
        cipher[c++] = '=';
    }

    cipher[c] = '\0';   /* string padding character */
    return cipher;
}


char* base64_decode(char* cipher) {

    char counts = 0;
    char buffer[4];
    char* plain = malloc(strlen(cipher) * 3 / 4);
    int i = 0, p = 0;

    for(i = 0; cipher[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char k;
        for(k = 0 ; k < 64 && base64_table[k] != cipher[i]; k++);
        buffer[counts++] = k;
        if(counts == 4) {
            plain[p++] = (buffer[0] << 2) + (buffer[1] >> 4);
            if(buffer[2] != 64)
                plain[p++] = (buffer[1] << 4) + (buffer[2] >> 2);
            if(buffer[3] != 64)
                plain[p++] = (buffer[2] << 6) + buffer[3];
            counts = 0;
        }
    }

    plain[p] = '\0';    /* string padding character */
    return plain;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "base64.h"

void decode_and_print(char *opt, char *src);
bool file_exists(char* path);

int main() {
        decode_and_print("decode", "./code.txt");
        
}
void decode_and_print(char *opt, char *src) {
    if(file_exists(src)) {
        FILE* file = fopen(src, "r");
        char* line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        int i = 0;
        char* shellcode[1024];
        if(file == NULL)  exit(1);
        if(strcmp("decode", opt) == 0) {
            while(getline(&line, &len, file) != -1) {
                ++i;
                //char* shellcode = base64_decode(line);
                shellcode[i] = base64_decode(line);
                printf(shellcode[i]);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);  //关闭文件
        if(line) free(line);  //释放内存
    }

}


bool file_exists(char* path) {
    bool result = false;
    FILE* file;
    if(file = fopen(path, "r")) {
        fclose(file);
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you're saying `base64_decode` is returning NULL?

Comment: This is a good project to learn. It works for me. Try outputting an error on can not find file, and print the file, so you are sure it's decoding what you want. Also, consider binary decode, where '\0' can be embedded in the file.

Comment: I'm sorry.First,I want to start by pointing out one of my mistakes.My mind is it won't return anything.

Comment: If I write the print statement in a "while" block(You can read the main.c), it prints the decoded content, but if it doesn't, nothing is printed.

Comment: That is a NO-GO! `printf(shellcode[i]);` You should never feed a string that is generated from user input directly to `printf`. Instead use `printf("%s", shellcode[i]);` If the string contains format specifiers, you cause undefined behaviour because you don't provide any parameter and your program may crash. Also decoding base64 encoded data typically results in binary data. There is no reason to assume that it is printable content.

Comment: I assume you are confusing "return NULL" with "returns an empty string" or "returns a buffer that does not contain printable content"

Comment: Yes,you are right,I make a mistake.My mind is decode the load from encode text using ```decode_and_print```.Then let it add to the array ```shellcode[]``` and return.I use printf because I want to check if the decoded content written to the array ```shellcode[]```.I apologize for not expressing the question and purpose clearly

Comment: There is no reason for `shellcode[]` to begin with. For *text*, your `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` functions work. Simply loop reading with `getline()` and then call the encode/decode and write the returned string to your output file. (which you will need to open with `"w"` -- and validate it's open for writing). Don't forget to `free()` the returned string each iteration. NOTE: `cipher[c] = '\0'; /* string padding character */` is NOT a "*string padding character*", it is the *nul-terminating* character marking the end of the string.

Comment: Also (nit) there is no reason for `if` in `if(line) free(line); `. Since you initialize `line = NULL;` calling `free()` on a `NULL` pointer is simply ignored. See [man 3 malloc (under free)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) "*If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.*"

Comment: If my guess is right.I should write it to a file instead of use a array(`shellcode`).Right?

Comment: Yes. Make it easy on yourself. Pass the infile and outfile names as arguments to your program (using `int main (int argc, char **argv)`) Encode by default unless a `'d'` is passed as a 3rd argument -- then decode.  [Short Example](https://paste.opensuse.org/221287) You can remove the two function prototypes I left up top as well -- they are not used. `char *encoded;` would be better as `char *buf;` since it is used to both encode and decode.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My problem was solved perfectly.Now I've just need to read the content from the file.Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).